# In python how to print vertically while using for loop

Tags: python-3.x, printing

I need to get the output as:

```
Player Name     Points
Charl            9
Bettina          9
Denni            4
Ann              4
```

But I'm getting like this:

```
Player Name     Points
Charl         9
Bettina       9
Denni       4
Ann       4
```

This is my code:

```
def main():
    l=[]
    s=[9,4,9,4]
    p=['Bettina','Ann','Charl','Denni']
    for n in range(len(p)):
        l.append([p[n],s[n]])
    print(l)
    l.sort(key = lambda l: (l[1],l[0]), reverse=True)
    print("Player Name     Points")
    for i in range(len(l)):
        print(f"{l[i][0]:>2s}",end='     ')    
        print(f"  {l[i][1]:<2d}")

main()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use ljust().

```
print(l[i][0].ljust(16),l[i][1])
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
print("Player Name     Points")
for name,pts in zip(p,s):
    print(f"{name:<18s}{pts:<2d}")

#Player Name     Points
#Bettina          9 
#Ann              4 
#Charl            9 
#Denni            4
```

Comment: I need to get in descending order of points and in alphabetical order of name.

Comment: Just add sorting.